# Wireshark dissector: There is a header before Ethernet packets

Tags: wireshark

I have my own protocol but I don't know how to create my own wireshark dissector..
Ethernet packets looks like:

```
[Dst MacAddress][Src MacAddress][Ethertype].....
```

My protocol add a header:

```
[My protocol header][Dst MacAddress][Src MacAddress][Ethertype].....
```

I want to dissect the header and use the Ethernet Protocol to dissect the remaining, what should I do?

Comment: Try to ask at the Wireshark developer list.